# $modal in ui-router with service

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have a very simple $modal feature that opens up a pop up and performs a simple get() to display information. I got the pop up working but I can't get my service to make the API call correctly.

Here's my ui-routing page:

```
.state('rates.rate.runexperiment', {
    url: "/runexperiment",
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', function($stateParams, $state, $modal){
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "templates/ExpsResults.html",
            controller: ['$scope', 'ExpsService', function($scope, ExpsService) {

                $scope.expResults = null;

                $scope.getExpResults = function(){
                    ExpsService.getExpResults('1000').get().then(function(response){
                        $scope.expResults = response;
                    });
                };

                $scope.dismiss = function() {
                    $scope.$dismiss();
                };

                $scope.getExpResults();
            }]
        }).result.then(function(){
            if (result) {
                return $state.transitionTo('rates.rate');
            }
        });
    }]
})
```

I tried putting the service injection in the onEnter part but to no prevail. When the user clicks on the popup button I get this in the console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function at 

ExpsService.getExpResults('1000').get().then(function(response){
```

which makes me believe this controller isn't getting access to my ExpsService in my service dir (which btw works everywhere else in my angular app).

Here's my service call I'm making using Restangular:

```
expResults = null,

getExpResults: function(expId){
    var self=this;
    return Restangular.one('rates/exp', expId).get().then(function(response){
        self.expResults = response;
        $log.debug('getExpResults', self.self.expResults);
        return self.expResults;
    });
},
```

Would it make sense to put my controller in it's own file and try it that way? Any opinions on how to get my factory/service call working in here?

Comment: How does `ExpsService.getExpResults('1000')` method look like? Does it expose a method called `get` which returns a promise?

Comment: I believe the `ExpsService` has been injected successfully, the error should be either there is no method `getExpResults` or `get` or `then`.

Comment: @PSL I updated the original post with my service call

Comment: @Garuuk Just try doing `ExpsService.getExpResults('1000').then...`

Comment: @PSL Ah I didn't catch it, yes removing the .get in my controller got it working.

ps. the $state.transitionTo() doesn't seem to be changing my state back to rates.rate  - do I need $state injected into the controller?

Comment: O wait nvm, I need to change $dismiss to $close. Thanks again!